# Japanese girlfriend visiting me in Canada - questions at border control?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, japanese-citizens

My girlfriend from Japan came to Canada to visit me last summer July 2022 and departed Oct 2022. We decided to meet again this January 20,2023 to celebrate our 1 year and she wanted to spend time with before she starts her job this April 1,2023. She has her ticket already and she will be returning to Japan by March 20, 2023 to attend her job training this March 24.

My question is: Will this raise a concern to the immigration officers? I told her to bring her acceptance letter to convince the officer that she won’t be staying here in Canada indefinitely.

---

The following was posted as an answer but has been edited into the question as it belongs here:
She decided to stay 2 weeks instead as she needs to go back to Japan for her job training. She changed her mind.

Edit: will this still impose a big problem to the immigration officer since it’s only 2 weeks? I got the job acceptance letter translated and it is stated that she’s starting her job April 1. She also has her return ticket along with it.

Comment: How likely is it that the immigration officer or a colleague on duty can read an acceptance letter in Japanese? GF might consider getting a certified document translation to English or French.

Comment: It wouldn't be called International Airport if there's no translator

Comment: on site translators in Vancouver are present

Comment: @Latrell I believe there may be on site translators (although it will add time if they are needed), but that’s not the definition of an international airport.

Comment: I figured, I’d better off finding a website to get her paper translated so it will help.

Comment: @Latrell maybe, but there are many languages and no airport can have translators for all of them on site. They'll probably have a means to access off-site resources of course.

Comment: @Latrell You need a professional translator for any document that is looked at by officials. Computer translation is not fully accurate and you need to not have errors or misunderstandings here.

Comment: I found an official a certified Japanese translator

Comment: I’m just scared that she will be denied entry for some reason and my anxiety is just giving me a hard time right now. We’re both scared. Maybe It’s because I’ve been watching too much of border security and heard a lot horror stories. Sigh

Comment: A TV show is not necessarily a reliable source, but you can learn from them that they can reject you. On the brighter side, remember that Customs officers are not trying to look unprofessional or arbitrary. They need a reason to reject someone, not necessarily one you agree with, but some reason a superior will approve. People do not get rejected willy-nilly. If you play by the rules your chances of getting through are pretty high.

Comment: Might the officer have any reason to suspect that the "girlfriend" is not genuinely interested in a relationship with you?  Who paid for the flights, who is paying for her expenses during the stay, are you giving her money or items of significant value?  If the trip is "all expenses paid" then it could be considered a "working holiday".

Comment: @John Mee she paid for the ticket and she has saved up 3000 and her 2 credit cards to cover her expenses.

Comment: @Latrell having done voluntary translation at border controls at munich airport (stating the name specifically as it's a big "international" airport in the west) several times, I can assure you that you cannot count on there being translators available directly at border control. If they pull you aside for further examination they may have translators they could get there, but that's something travelers ideally want to avoid.

Answer (score 28):

It will count against her that she is visiting her boyfriend (obvious motivation for overstay), and that with the second visit, she'd have spend a lot of time in relatively short period in Canada. The boundaries between "living in Japan and occasionally visiting Canada" and "living in Canada and occasionally visiting Japan" are getting somewhat blurred here.

Having a job lined up in Japan is definitely working in her favour: This is a reason for her to return as planned, and also an indication that the "where is actually the centre of her life"-issue is about to be resolved with "Japan" as answer. The more attractive the job the better. She should definitely have the appropriate documentation on her[1]. It will also count in her favour that she returned home as expected last time.

Overall, there is nothing inherently wrong with her planned visit. On the other hand, the overall situation seems to be amongst the most common settings which leads to refusal of entry for citizens of developed countries.

[1] Showing the job letter in Japanese of course isn't going to help much, unless the border guard was already about to let her pass anyway. I would hope that if she gets into secondary inspection, it would be possible to get someone capable of reading a little Japanese in there, but I wouldn't count on it. Translating it into English and getting someone to stamp it would be prudent.

Comment: She will be working as a kindergarten teacher in Japan this April 1.

Comment: Having a return ticket before that date would also be good.  And in generally Japan is not viewed as a high-risk country for overstayers.

Comment: @lambshaanxy she has her return ticket booked already. She’s returning to Japan this March 20.

Comment: @Arno does she need to get her job letter translated to english?

Comment: @Latrell Good catch. I've added a comment.

Comment: I will tell her to include the original copy together with the translation

Comment: And does need to be notarized too?

Comment: @Latrell it helps, but will probably not be needed. With the return ticket and her country of origin a regular translation will LIKELY be enough and if not there will of course be a delay while a Japanese speaker is called in to verify the original.

Comment: @Latrell, you might suggest to your GF that she ask the school for an English translation on official school letterhead. AIUI, many (most? all?) Japanese schools teach English, so there should be several fluent English speakers there, and a copy on school letterhead that matches the Japanese letterhead would likely carry additional weight of credibility.

Answer (score 4):

Japanese citizen here. I visited Canada twice in a very short window of time (like 10 days) in Winter 2017. I flew into Vancouver from Singapore (to make it more complicated I was a Singapore resident with a Japanese passport) first. In Vancouver my Singapore residence card was lost which caused me a problem at the border control.

I crossed the Canadian-USA border to visit Seattle from Vancouver. I had no problem with the USA side. I got into trouble when I tried to cross back into Canada from the USA as my flight back to Singapore was originated in Vancouver.

Unfortunately, the Canadian officer (let's call him A) had a tough day, he tried to detain me. He and his colleague B searched my phone and all my belongings. The A did not believe me saying I was a Singapore resident as my Singapore Id was lost, no way to convince him.

The B was nicer. As soon as he looked into my postcards or tickets to tourist attractions in Seattle/Vancouver he decided to release me. But the B gave me the following warning: always print out my flight ticket to leave Canada.

In your case, I would do the following. In the event your gf got into trouble with the border guard I would flash my return ticket to leave Canada. Plus I would give them your phone number and have them call you. Then you could tell them that she is not visiting Canada indefinitely.

I hope all this makes sense and wish your gf a pleasant stay in Canada.

Comment: Thank you, yes I would print out a ticket

Comment: I highly doubt that boarder guards would consider the assurances of a boyfriend to be credible evidence that a girl is planning on leaving the country on time. As noted in [Arno's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/178045/42899), the return ticket and a copy of a job acceptance letter (in the original Japanese and a certified translation to English) will carry _far_ more weight.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the return ticket and the proof of employment, in English if possible, there are other issues to convince a possibly overzealous border office to let her through.

If she's coming to stay 2 months only, be consistent:

- Restrict the luggage. She probably won't need summer clothes. (Does Canada have summer anyway?). Carrying some is a huge red flag.  In the same way, she won't need tonnes of Japanese food.
- Take care with the messages and other stuff in the smartphone. Canada allows border authorities to search through the phone, even without any concrete trigger. Some searches like 'japanese teaching jobs in Vancouver' might be performed out of curiosity, but are fishy.
- Mind the answers to the customs officer. He might well ask if she's planning to visit Canada regularly for 2 months from now on. Is saying yes consistent with her job prospect? Is answering no consistent with what her boyfriend would answer?
- Also make sure that nothing significant has changed since she was granted the eTA.

Comment: I’m just really scared because they might deny her from entering Canada for some reason and I’ve been really stress about this. We’re both scared. I have watched people in Border security show that were rejected and heard a lot of stories about it. Plus her English is not as good like elementary English. I’ve doing best teaching her. Sigh

Comment: @Latrell You mention that your gf’s proposed second visit is to celebrate your 1 year together. Have you considered visiting your gf in Japan? Immigration officers might like to see reciprocal visits rather than one way

Comment: I can’t visit yet because I’m in school. I’ll be visiting her next year November. I’m also just waiting for my Canadian Citizenship

Comment: @Traveller why, is necessary?

Comment: Isn’t that selfish to do just because the other one cannot visit for some reasons, they won’t allow her to visit?

Comment: @Latrell I didn’t say it was necessary, nor that they won’t allow her to visit, I commented only that reciprocal visits can be seen as a positive. “Yes, my boyfriend has visited me in my home country” is a better reply than “no, he has never visited me”.

Comment: I can’t make a visit yet because I am waiting for my citizenship and finishing my school. I’ll be done by November next year and I will make my visit to Japan.

Comment: School I can see as an obstacle to foreign travel, but unless Japan has banned (or otherwise made it extremely difficult to get a visa), I can't see how your _current_ country of citizenship would prevent you from visiting her. Unless, of course, there are restrictions in place on your current visa to CA that would prevent you from doing additional traveling.

Comment: I would say even more strongly to delete anything on the phone AND on any electronic devices or storage media (SD cards, portable hard drives) that could in some way be misinterpreted or your GF would not want strangers rifling through and viewing.